# How do I turn the turtle module along with my mouse

Tags: python, mouse, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I've been wondering how the turtle would turn with your mouse (like many io games)

Is there a command or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen() # Create screen
t = turtle.Turtle('turtle') # Create turtle

def drag(x, y): # Define drag function
    t.ondrag(0)
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y))
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.ondrag(drag)

t.ondrag(drag) # Use function on turtle
wn.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT: As pointed out by @cdlane in the comments, the `0` in the `t.ondrag` method should optimally be `None`, as the former defines a new event function that throws an exception that isn't seen as it's protected by `except Exception: pass`.

Comment: I believe what you want is `t.ondrag(None)`, not `t.ondrag(0)` as the former disables the drag event but the latter defines a new event function that throws an exception that isn't seen as it's protected by `except Exception: pass`.  That is, as written, the code is throwing, catching and ignoring exceptions as you drag the mouse.  To reinforce this, try `t.ondrag('frog')` which also *works* but also spews passed over exceptions.